# Leak memory issue with Pax logging

Tags: logging, osgi, java.util.logging, eclipse-rap, pax

I'm using Pax logging in my RAP and OSGi project.

I used MAT to check and see the number of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display` object and `org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.UISessionImpl` object are as much as the time I refresh web application and memory become bigger.

When I uncheck **org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service** and **org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api** bundles in configuration the problem is gone. So I think Pax logging is the reason of this problem but I have no idea what happened.

Looking for any solution and idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to update Pax logging to latest version 1.8.1 and problem is gone.

1. [Pax logging API](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.1)
2. [Pax logging service](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.1)